# Python decorator for a class method to change the current object instance i.e, self

Tags: python, python-decorators

The following is my test code to have a decorator for a class method which can change the self (current object instance)

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 5

    def _change_x(self):
        print "in _change_x"
        def decorator(f):
            print "in decorator"
            def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
                print "in wrapped"
                print args, kwargs
                self.x = 8
                f(*args, **kwargs)
            return wrapped
        return decorator

    @_change_x
    def print_x(self):
        print "in print_x, x: %d" % self.x
        return self.x

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = Test()
    print "Initial value for x: %d" % test.x
    print "Test if it changed? x: %d" % test.print_x()
```

The internal method wrapped in the decorator is not being invoked. Can any one help me pointing out the mistake in my test code.
I want this kind of decorator defined in a class, and is used to decorate few methods in that class to change the class members at the call time.

Comment: Can any one suggest me a way other than decorator to change the class members (for that instance) before each function call. I want the modification to be opaque for readability, thats why I am not modifying them in the start of the class method.

Comment: It's a bit hard for me to understand why you want to be changing things right before a function call... I don't know the problem at hand, but this seems like an unintuitive design pattern for anything use-case that I can try to think up (which is admittedly no use cases at the present ;-)).

Comment: @mgilson having an extra step inserted before many method calls is an extremely powerful debugging tool.  simply `print f` would indicate which methods are being called at various points throughout the course of the program.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen -- Sure, I can buy that (sort of ... `pdb` is still a better option IMHO).  But even in that case, you aren't _changing_ anything, merely inspecting.

Comment: what if you want to count the number of times the method was called? keep a count attribute and increment it right before each call, yes I know there are useful tools for this too but creating your own decorator is the easiest way to control which action is taken.

Answer (score 3):

First, lets consider why your code *doesn't* work...

At the time when `_change_x` is invoked, the class is still under construction, so there *can't* be any instances of the class.  Because of this, your `self` argument is misleading.  When it gets called, `self` is actually the function `print_x`.  Obviously adding things to `self` won't change your instance of `Test` because `self` isn't an instance of `Test` :-).  *In other words, there is nothing special about defining the decorator function inside the class.*  The only thing that it does is it also adds a function `_change_x` to the namespace that you could call at other times.

How do we get this working then?  Well, the answer is to realize that `_change_x` is only decorating methods.  In that case, the first argument to the wrapper function will be `self` (just like in a normal method), so we can drop it in there and work with it inside of `wrapped`:  This works:

```
class Test(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 5

    def _change_x(f):
        print "in _change_x"
        def wrapped(self, *args, **kwargs):
            print "in wrapped"
            print args, kwargs
            self.x = 8
            return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped

    @_change_x
    def print_x(self):
        print "in print_x, x: %d" % self.x
        return self.x

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = Test()
    print "Initial value for x: %d" % test.x
    print "Test if it changed? x: %d" % test.print_x()
```

But it turns out that you don't need to define the decorator in the class at all.  After all, as I said earlier -- There is nothing special about putting it in the class...:

```
def _change_x(f):
    print "in _change_x"
    def wrapped(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print "in wrapped"
        print args, kwargs
        self.x = 8
        return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped


class Test(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 5

    @_change_x
    def print_x(self):
        print "in print_x, x: %d" % self.x
        return self.x

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = Test()
    print "Initial value for x: %d" % test.x
    print "Test if it changed? x: %d" % test.print_x()
```

Comment: "_I want this kind of decorator defined in a class_" would kind of suggest that the OP specifically wanted the decorator in the class definition

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen -- Yeah, I'm not really understanding the use-case here (yet).  Maybe it'll become more clear if OP updates the question/comments?

Answer (score 0):

the issue is that _change_x is the decorator itself, and the wrapper needs to take self as an argument:

```
def _change_x(f):
    print "in _change_x decorator"
    def wrapped(self,*args, **kwargs):
        print "in wrapped"
        print args, kwargs
        self.x = 8
        f(self,*args, **kwargs)
        #maybe return f(*args,**kw)?
    return wrapped
```

this may be confusing to put in the class definition though since, being a decorator, it isn't a method on an instance so you probably either want to delete it from the class scope after using it or define it outside the class scope (still works same way)

edit: if you defined `_change_x` in the class then at the bottom of the class definition added `_change_x = staticmethod(_change_x)` you would still have the function available as a staticmethod after the class definition, although you cannot do this until you are done with it in the same scope. (unless you did `@_change_x.__get__(0)` which is really unnecessary)